# stretch line chart to same length in excel

Tags: excel, graph, plot, charts, linechart

I have two series with data points in excel.

The data looks like this:

[image]

If I create a simple line chart it looks like this:

[image]

However, I would need the red line to be of the same length as the blue line since the data of both series stretches over the same time. Unfortunately I dont have the timestamps of each data point. But I guess there must be another way to do this.

It should be something like *stretch the line over the whole x-axis of the graph*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have start and end timestamps for both, you can fill empty places with
    =#N/A

That is, the `not available` error.

If you do not have the end/start timestamps for either, you will need to calculate them yourself.

Picture:

[image]

Comment: I can calculate the timestamps. But how should it look like in the table, to be able to create a proper chart based on the timestamps?

Comment: Do you mean like this with the timestamps (atime and btime columns): http://i.stack.imgur.com/RxLea.png

how to create the graph then?

Comment: I uploaded a picture - worth a thousand words in this case, I guess.

Comment: okay. I understand now. my problem is that in this solution, I need to fill in the #n/as manually. or I need to do some sort of preprocessing to fill in the data at the correct timestamps with a lookup. thanks. I think I can get there.

Comment: VLOOKUP is your friend there: it will even result in #N/A when something is not found.